# MySQL database " create table " query

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`friendlist` (
  `Lid` INT NOT NULL,
  `Pid` INT NOT NULL,
  `Fid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Fid`),
  INDEX `Pid_idx` (`Pid` ASC),
  INDEX `Lid_idx` (`Lid` ASC, `Pid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Lid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Lid` , `Pid`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`loginauthentication` (`Lid` , `Pid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Pid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Pid`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`person` (`Pid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Statement:

Comment: can you post the definition of the referenced tables please? maybe the data types of one of their PKs do not match that of your FK.

Comment: Did you try searching for that error message? A google search for `mysql error 1215` brings up several SE pages where someone ran into this exact error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was try execute your SQL and I found that the column *Pid* dosent exist in the table *loginauthentication*, but I added column and run again your SQL and it worked!

```
ALTER TABLE `loginauthentication`ADD COLUMN `Pid`  int(11) NULL AFTER `Lid`

[SQL] CREATE TABLE  `friendlist` (
  `Lid` INT NOT NULL,
  `Pid` INT NOT NULL,
  `Fid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Fid`),
  INDEX `Pid_idx` (`Pid` ASC),
  INDEX `Lid_idx` (`Lid` ASC, `Pid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Lid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Lid` , `Pid`)
    REFERENCES `loginauthentication` (`Lid` , `Pid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Pid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Pid`)
    REFERENCES `person` (`Pid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.179ms
```

Grettings!

Answer (score -1):

Run this DDL first:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
```

then do the query

```
CREATE TABLE test.friendlist ( 
Lid INT NOT NULL,
  Pid INT NOT NULL,
  Fid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 INDEX Pid_idx (Pid ASC),
 INDEX Lid_idx (Lid ASC, Pid ASC),
 CONSTRAINT Lid FOREIGN KEY (Lid , Pid) REFERENCES test.loginauthentication (Lid , Pid) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
CONSTRAINT Pid FOREIGN KEY (Pid) REFERENCES test.person (Pid) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

EX: Used my own reference tables modify accordingly

```
mysql> show create table friendlistl

| friendlist | CREATE TABLE `friendlist` (
  `Lid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Fid`),
  KEY `Pid_idx` (`Pid`),
  KEY `Lid_idx` (`Lid`,`Pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `Lid` FOREIGN KEY (`Lid`, `Pid`) REFERENCES `test` (`Lid`, `Pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Pid` FOREIGN KEY (`Pid`) REFERENCES `test` (`idn`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: What's the point in having constraints if you're going to just turn them all off and hack the table in? Terrible.